# Select dense_rank() along with MAX (dense_rank() ) in all r ows

Tags: sql, postgresql, max, dense-rank

I've a query like

```
select dense_rank() over(order by A.claim_id) as "Claim Count", 
A.person_cpr as "Unique member ID" from my_table as A
```

I need to get the MAX of the above dense_rank() to be appended with all rows as another column.

How can I do it? Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean something like this? `with j AS (
  select dense_rank() over(order by A.claim_id) as "Claim Count", 
  A.person_cpr as "Unique member ID" from my_table as A
)
select *, max("Claim Count") over () from j`

Comment: `max("Claim Count")` - can't use column aliases in places other than aliases in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting what you need for that part, you could use it as a CTE. ie:

```
with claims as (
select dense_rank() over(order by A.claim_id) as "Claim Count", 
A.person_cpr as "Unique member ID" 
from my_table as A
)
select "Claim Count", "Unique member ID", 
   max("Claim Count") over (partition by "Unique member ID") as "Max Claim Count"
from claims;
```

Comment: `max("Claim Count")` - can't use column aliases in places other than aliases in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses.

Comment: @art, what do you mean? Where did you see column alias used? It is column name, not column alias. Read again.

Comment: All that I needed is `select dense_rank() over(order by ccd.claim_id ASC) as "Claim Count",
dense_rank() OVER (order by ccd.claim_id) + dense_rank() OVER (order by ccd.claim_id desc) - 1 as "MAX CLIAMS"`. Thanks for your suggestion.